# Разработка виджета

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, виджет

Изучаю разработку под android на java, есть идея о создании приложения с упором на экранный виджет. Хотел спросить ряд вещей у знающих людей (возможно, некоторые из них глупы и абсурдны, но найти информацию по этим виджетам очень тяжело, следовательно, про работу с ними я знаю очень мало)

- Возможно ли по нажатию определенной кнопки в основном приложении отсылать  данные (строковый массив) в сам виджет, например, по средствам каких-либо интентов?
- Возможно ли долгосрочно хранить данный массив в памяти самого виджета?
- Возможно ли использовать в виджете RecyclerView?
- Может ли виджет производить какие-либо изменения в БД основного приложения или в принципе передавать данные основной программе?
- Возможно ли использование кнопок на виджете для управления самим виджетом и его обновления? (Например, у нас есть элемент TextView, содержащий предложение из определённого массива, и по нажатию на кнопку виджета это предложение меняется на следующее из этого массива)
- Может ли сам виджет генерировать уведомления?

Заранее благодарен за ответы хотя бы на часть вопросов. Если можете поделиться какими-то рускоязычными ресурсами по данной тематике - будет просто замечательно.

Comment: думаю лучше сначала почитать оф.док. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets буквально сразу есть список разрешенных View